# Refresh WPF UI after changing style color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, user-interface

I created a Template in a `ResourceDictionary`.
I have created a window in order to change the ThemeColor.
This colors is binded to my `ResourceDictionary`.

**Here is my ResourceDictionary :**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Phoenix_CRM" >


    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DegradeCouleurTheme" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ColorBegin}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ColorEnd}"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I created a CParameters class in order to set the color parameters. The two color composing the gradient are save in a DataBase. This class aims at Load/Save the color, and apply it.

**Here is my Class for changing the color :**

```
    public class CParametres : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private  Color m_ThemeColorGradientBegin;
        public  Color ThemeColorGradientBegin
        {
            get { return m_ThemeColorGradientBegin; }
            set
            {
                m_ThemeColorGradientBegin = value;
                ColorBegin = m_ThemeColorGradientBegin;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("ColorBegin");
            }
        }

        private  Color m_ThemeColorGradientEnd;
        public  Color ThemeColorGradientEnd
        {
            get { return m_ThemeColorGradientEnd; }
            set
            {
                m_ThemeColorGradientEnd = value;
                ColorEnd = m_ThemeColorGradientEnd;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("ColorEnd");
            }
        }

        public static Color ColorBegin;
        public static Color ColorEnd;


        public CParametres()
        {
            ....
            ....
        }

        public void LoadGradientDefault()
        {
            ThemeColorGradientBegin   =   (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#00b6e7");
            ThemeColorGradientEnd     =   (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#0086d6");
        }

        public void LoadParams()
        {
            if (ReadParamFromDB() == true)
            {
                setThemeGradient(m_ThemeColorGradientBegin, m_ThemeColorGradientEnd);
            }
        }

        public void setThemeGradient(Color ColorBegin, Color ColorEnd)
        {
            this.ThemeColorGradientBegin = ColorBegin;
            this.ThemeColorGradientEnd = ColorEnd;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void FirePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

When I change the color, I need to quit and re-run my application in order to see the changes. Anyone know of forcing to apply directly the new colors please?

Anyone could explain me what is the tips in order to refresh the UI please?

Comment: Your XAML is still referencing the static properties so change notifications will not occur.  See my answer for how to do the binding

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DynamicResource for all resource colors & styles instead of StaticResource.

Using DynamicResource, all your changes styles will be reflected in UI.

Update:

When ever you use Brush, you need to give the Brush in this way

```
<Setter Property="Foreground">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I just tried to use DynamicRessource : It's better : If I open a new window, the color are OK, nevertheless, the current window ( window already open aren't refreshed with the new color ).

Comment: I don't understand how to use your code with my LinearGradient, could you explain me please ? Thanks

Comment: Try adding the LinearGradient Resource in the Window instead of ResourceDictionary

Comment: I have a lot of Window, so, it's not a good solution for me :(

Comment: Please let us know, how you changing the color

Comment: I edited my post with added the class( I Clean it for a better view :) ) (-->The fireevent don't appear to be ok, i think it's because of my static porperty )

Comment: If you are Notifying something, then bind the Color property, instead of using it Static

Comment: So, you are saying that i need to avoid the static keywords ? But apparently i need to staty static for the binded so...difficult to understand :( Could you please give me the right modification in the xaml please ? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for property change events to occur.  Unfortunately that means you need an instance to operate on rather than a static.

If you create a static Property that returns a singleton instance you can do the following

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Phoenix_CRM" >


    <LinearGradientColor x:Key="DegradeCouleurTheme" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{Binding ColorBegin, Source={x:Static ns:CParametres.Instance}}" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding ColorEnd, Source={x:Static ns:CParametres.Instance}}" />
    </LinearGradientColor>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Example of singleton

```
public class CParameters : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    var handle = PropertyChanged;
    if (handle != null) handle(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private static readonly CParameters instance = new CParameters();

  public static CParameters Instance {
     get { return instance; }
  }

  private Color colorBegin;

  private Color colorEnd;

  public Color ColorBegin {
    get { return colorBegin; }
    set {
      if (value != colorBegin) {
        colorBegin=value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ColorBegin");
      }
    }
  }


  public Color ColorEnd {
    get { return colorEnd; }
    set { 
     if (value != colorEnd) {
       colorEnd = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("ColorEnd");
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: But it won't fire for static properties

Comment: I don't know how to use a singleton :(